# Calling different method from .ashx file through jQuery Ajax request

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm working on an `ASP.NET Web Forms` application where in the front end I have `jquery DataTable` and it was a bit difficult at first to operate with the queries from and to the `dataTable` I saw an example where `.ashx` file was used for this purposed and it was working fine for me too so I end up using `.ashx` file to deal with my `dataTable` however now I need to make some `Ajax` requests from different places and till now I was writing all the code inside here:

```
public class TData : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        // Those parameters are sent by the plugin
        var iDisplayLength = int.Parse(context.Request["iDisplayLength"]);
        //more code...
    }
}
```

but it's getting harder to keep all this logic in one place so I want to call different methods but at the same time keeping them at the same class `Tdata` so all the logic for the `dataTable` is kept in one place.

I tried this:

```
       $.ajax({
            url: "/TData.ashx",
            type: "GET",
            data: { method: 'Test', args: { blabla: 'blabla' } },
        });
```

with this code on the server side:

```
    public object Test(string blabla)
    {
        return string.Format("Hello {0}!", blabla);
    }
```

but this method actually is never called and it seems that using this syntax the request is going directly to `public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)`. I am using `.NET 4.5` so is there a way to add additional methods in the same class and call them with `jQuery Ajax` from the client side?

Comment: Have you looked into `WebAPI` already? Seems like the better tool for the job...

Comment: @ChrFin Yeah, but I'm kinda obligated to keep it in the `Web Forms` boundries due to colleges qualification, experience, and stuff like that. I'm looking at direction like using `.asmx` or making the `.ashx` option work.

Comment: I am quite certain it is easier for your colleges to understand `WebAPI` code "they don't know" then some `*.ashx`-hacks. `*.asmx` web-services are not that different from `WebAPI` aside from routing and some newer features can be used (and they are also not "in the `Web Forms` boundries" IMO). => maybe talk to your colleges again and try to convince them to use the tool built for the job...

Comment: P.S.: With "not that different" I mean "how they look like" not "how they work in the background"!

Comment: I'm aware of the `WebAPI` even though I'm not experienced with it. When we talked about what is gonna be used for this project I actually suggested it. The decision was not to use it.. So this is my reality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want to stick with the `*.ashx`-handler you could redirect the flow based on your `method` parameter:

```
public class TData : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        switch (context.Request["method"])
        {
            case "test":
                Test(context);
                break;
            //other methods
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("unknown method");
        }
    }

    public void Test(HttpContext context)
    {
        // Those parameters are sent by the plugin
        var iDisplayLength = int.Parse(context.Request["iDisplayLength"]);
        //more code...

        context.Response.Write(String.Format("Hello {0}!", blabla));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm gonan use this, since it seems that there's no "right" way to do this kind of stuff..

Comment: The "right way" would be `WebAPI` IMO - some times colleges must be "forced to use new stuff", but after using them they start to like them very quickly - happened to me not only once...

Comment: `context.Request["method"]` returns null where in ajax, I passed data as `data: { method: 'Vendor' },`